# Create a .desktop file that opens and execute a command in a terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, .desktop

I would like to know how to write the `Exec` command of a .desktop file to open a new terminal and execute a shell script in it. The shell script is working and accessible by all users. When launching the script from the terminal everything works, but it doesn't when trying to launch the script from a .desktop file.

Here are some combinations I have already tried:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'echo hello'
Exec=sh -c 'gnome-terminal echo hello'
Exec=sh -c 'echo hello'
Exec=echo hello
```

The .desktop terminal option is set to true.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The content of your desktop file should look like (see [how to create a .desktop file using a text editor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Using_a_text_editor)):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Test        
Comment=Test the terminal running a command inside it
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'echo hello;$SHELL'"
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Or:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Test        
Comment=Test the terminal running a command inside it
Exec=bash -c 'echo hello;$SHELL'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true 
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

In the first case, the `Terminal` field is set to `false` (perhaps contrary to your expectations) and in second case is set to `true`, but the result is in both cases the same.

Comment: The first solution works for me, so I stick with it. Do you know why there has to be $SHELL?

Comment: It worked for me , however i want to launch a command with sudo , then when use launcher created it opens terminal asking-me for password . How do i launch a command and prevent this behavior ?

Comment: @EliasAlves A bit late, but for anyone else reading this: you cannot expect to run commands that require root privileges without being required to authenticate yourself. (Unless you explicitly configure your system to do that, which is generally a *bad* idea.)

Comment: I think the question is: how to make sure the terminal appears so that the terminal doesn't disappear so that we can enter the credentials

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Hello
Exec=sh -c 'echo hello; $SHELL'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

---

As stated in [desktop entry specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html#recognized-keys), `Terminal=true` tells the launcher to launch your script in a terminal window. The chosen Terminal Emulator depends on your default applications settings and Desktop Environment. In GNOME, it is gnome-terminal, in KDE, it is Konsole. (Without DE, in plain WM there is a bug in xdg-open, and `Terminal=true` just ignored, [see issue](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92514))

You need this line to run your script and launch a shell after it.

```
Exec=sh -c 'echo hello; $SHELL'
```

1. `sh -c 'COMMAND'` run the "sh" binary found in $PATH which
   executes COMMAND (on many systems, `sh` is the symbolic link to
   `bash`, but for portability "sh" is prefered)
2. `echo hello; $SHELL` does two things. First, it runs `echo hello`
   and then, after the execution of this command, launches $SHELL.

If you will **not** add some command that waits for you to exit, a terminal emulator will just run your program and **exit**.

---

P.S. If you just want not to close your terminal, you can do

```
Exec=sh -c 'echo hello; read'
```

Or

```
Exec=sh -c 'echo hello; sleep 5'
```

(read will wait for you to press Enter, sleep will just wait 5 seconds)

P.P.S `$SHELL` probably will be the same as last section in `/etc/passwd` in line with your user.

```
$ man login
```

> The value for $HOME, $USER, $SHELL, $PATH, $LOGNAME, and $MAIL are set
> ac‐
> cording  to  the  appropriate fields in the password entry.

Comment: I do not think your statement, "The chosen Terminal Emulator depends on your default applications settings and Desktop Environment." is true. I have Xterm as my default terminal, but using 'Terminal=true' doesn't open in Xterm. How would this be enforced, here? It seems like this should be expected behavior.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, it is opened, but in another terminal? And what launcher (or DE) are you using?

Comment: `Terminal=true` doesn't open the terminal for me in gnome, although `gnome-terminal` does work in a terminal to open *another* terminal.

Answer (score 3):

```
!#/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -e YOUR_COMMANDS
```

Make the above file. Don't forget to `sudo chmod +x filename.sh`

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that the terminal disappears immediately and a user is not capable to enter something.

Comment: i forgot what it is called but I i think there is a option to keep the terminal up. It might be `hold`

Answer (score 3):

Simply add

```
;$SHELL
```

at the end of your commands.

Like for me `snapd` isn't something using full bandwidth of system to refresh snaps anytime almost I work at night.

So this worked for me to create a `.sh` file linked to a `.desktop` file.
Contents for `.sh` file were

```
echo <your password> | sudo -S systemctl stop snapd.service
sudo systemctl disable snapd.service;$SHELL
```

`-S` in the first line of the `.sh` file is used to send `STDINPUT` to the `sudo` command meaning direct execute without entering password.

Contents for the `.desktop` file were:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Test
Comment=Test the terminal running a command inside it
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "/scripts/disable_snap.sh"
Icon=terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this. First line of the text file is !#/bin/bash

Subsequent lines of the text file are the commands (the shell script).

Save the file as something.sh

Open the properties of the file and enable run file as a program.

Now, when the file is double clicked, I get the option to run it.

Comment: It works for me no problems. Create the shell script, add the line !#/bin/bash as the first line. Allow the file to be run as an executable. Double click and select run in terminal. It just works.

Comment: Are you sure the terminal isn't just closing because the shell script has finished ? At the beginning of your script put sleep 30, does the terminal stay open for 30 seconds ?