# How to login to remote server using ssh with script in ubuntu terminal

Tags: ssh

I'm new to Ubuntu. I want to access a remote server using terminal by using the shortcut key. For example, to access server Y, I will give `ssh Y` all the time. Just want to write a script to access the server so that I can call it every time and easy to remember. Which file do I need to add the command in?. How to run it after logging into my system?

Comment: You can set up bash alias, eg. like [in this asnwer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

Answer (score 2):

Use `~/.ssh/config`:

Add a host:

```
Host y
  HostName domain.com
  Port 666
  User username
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-domain
```

And then access your host from a terminal:

```
ssh y
```

Also, you can create a shortcut to your terminal that opens a ssh session right away. Save this to a `y.desktop` file and place it in your `~/Desktop` folder:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=domain.com
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'ssh y'"
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Sure, there are number of ways on how you can bind a shortcut to some actions. The simplest in Unity is to use it's own settings: *System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts*. You can bind one to execute `ssh y`.

Comment: Any reason for `bash -c 'ssh y'` instead of a direct `ssh y`?

Comment: No. I have copied this code from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal). I guess changing this to just `ssh y` will work as well.