# XTerm instead of Terminal in .desktop

Tags: command-line, bash, .desktop, xterm

I have this `.desktop` file set to update my software:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Update Software
Comment=Application
Exec=/home/david/Update_Script.sh
Icon=/home/david/Downloads/upgrade.jpg
Categories=Application;
Terminal=true
```

However, it launches [Terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/), where I would prefer [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/). So do not mark this as a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal). I want the file to open xterm and then close xterm when the script is done. Here is what the script looks like currently:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get clean
```

Do I need to add something to the `.desktop` file or to the script to make it open xterm (and close it when done)?

Comment: Why aren't you using `Exec=xterm -e /home/david/Update_Script.sh`, if you so insist on `xterm`?

Comment: @muru Sorry I am new to using .desktop files and shell scripts, didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.desktop` and the Ctrl-Alt-T shortcut all launch `x-terminal-emulator` , which is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator` , which in turn is a symlink to `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper`. In short, `gnome-terminal` aka Terminal is the default terminal emulator on Ubuntu.

If you want to use `xterm` for just one `.desktop` file , follow muru's suggestion in the comments and use use

```
Exec=xterm -e /path/to/script.sh
```

If you want to globally change the terminal that the system launches by default, run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Comment: You might want to add that he should remove the `Terminal=true` then. Else `gnome-terminal` will open, running `xterm`, running script :)