# How to login to SSH and have username and password automatically entered?

Tags: ssh, login, proxy, port-forwarding, putty

I've been using nothing but Windows for years. I'm transitioning to Linux and I'm trying to make the transition as easy as possible since I have almost no knowledge of Linux.

On Windows, I currently use desktop shortcuts with PuTTY as a quick and easy way to connect to different proxy servers. I have created shortcuts for PuTTY that allow me to simply double-click them which opens PuTTY, which connects to the server and supplies the username and password. Pretty much what is being done in this article: http://web.archive.org/web/20201203103040/http://jafty.com/blog/how-to-make-putty-automatically-login-with-user-and-password/

I need to forward certain local ports to certain ports on the proxy servers (e.g., L8888->localhost:2222) so I can specify multiple HTTP and SOCKS proxy settings in browsers and other apps.

Is there a way to mimic this "auto-login" that I'm doing on the Windows box or is there a better, more secure way of doing this on Ubuntu? The usernames and passwords are very complex and I need to connect and disconnect frequently. Unfortunately, I have no control over the servers so usernames/passwords have to be used.

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately, I have no control over the servers so usernames/passwords have to be used.

No, your servers likely have key-based authentication enabled. See [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login) on setting it up, so you can skip using passwords and use keys. (If you absolutely must use passwords for some insane reason, see another answer in that post using `ssh-pass`.

Then, you can create entries in `~/.ssh/config` like so:

```
Host proxy1
     Hostname some.server.or.ip
     User foo
     LocalForward 8888 localhost:2222
```

Here `proxy1` can be any name you choose, but `Hostname` should contain the actual server hostname or IP. (See [`man ssh_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ssh_config) for more options.) Having done that, in a terminal, do `ssh proxy1` in a terminal to start the port forwarding, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to quit (or run `exit`).

Or see [Create a .desktop file that opens and execute a command in a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/436891/158442) on how to start commands in a terminal from a shortcut (or "launcher").

Of course, [putty is available for Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=putty).

Comment: Thank you! I do not own the remote servers that I'm logging into so I cannot change the settings on those servers. If I'm understanding your response correctly, that means I cannot implement your first suggestion. Am I correct?

Comment: @Jeff try and see