# Where can I see the files installed by a package through terminal

Tags: command-line, system-installation

When ever I install a packaage (application) through terminal. it gets install but I'm not able to find it at my desktop, As you can see `winff` is installed:

[image: As you can see winff is installed]

However when I try to search it in dash I'm not able to find it:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
whereis <packagename>
```

and that should show you a path to the package.
If you want to have it on the desktop you can just create a link to the executable file, make a script running that file or use the linux implemented "add to desktop" function.

Comment: It's not really true have a look at my answer ;)

Comment: He wanted simply wanted help. My command did the trick. Yeah, you might have better solutions but for this particular problem he has one solution that he can remember not 10 commands that has to save somewhere to copy them always... But thanks for your answer, there were some news for me too :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to find about it. Before going farther you should know that some package does not come with binary files thus there is nothing to run with their name.

#### For commands

First we can use `whereis` command, it will tell us where a command's (not package) binary, source and manuals are located. you can run it like:

```
whereis perl
```

to get all information mentioned above about a command named `perl`, or like:

```
whereis -b perl
```

to only get the path of all `perl` binaries.

Another option is to use `which`, when I've got multiple binaries for a command, `which` tells me which one of them will be executed if I run that command, e.g:

```
which python
```

#### For packages

For packages, it's a different case; A package can involve multiple and completely different binaries.

one thing we can do is to use `dpkg -L <package-name>`, it will show all installed files from the package named `<package-name>`, eg:

```
dpkg -L coreutils
```

If I want to get a list only for binaries I can run it like this:

```
dpkg -L coreutils | grep /bin/
```

which outputs something like:

```
/bin/rmdir
/bin/uname
/bin/ln
/bin/cat
...
/usr/bin/nl
/usr/bin/arch
/usr/bin/tac
...
```

We can also use [Ubuntu online packages list](http://packages.ubuntu.com) to search for a package, for your package `winff`:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/all/winff/filelist
```

#### Icon/shortcut for commands

At the end if I want to have an icon for fast access to that application I can write a `.desktop` file for that command, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal) is more information about creating this files.