# How to install latest version Eclipse in Ubuntu-16.04

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse

I am getting older version of Eclipse when I install it from terminal, which is fine for C/C++ code, but I want to use java, basically for spring and maven, so I want a newer version.

Answer (score 2):

Download and install it from http://eclipse.org.

Here is the [link](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) to all different versions of eclipse.
You just have to extract and run it.

My instruction is:

1. Download it
2. Extract it in `/opt`

   ```
   sudo tar -xf /path/to/file -C /opt
   ```
3. Create a link to its binary

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin
   ```

Answer (score 0):

latest eclipse(oxygen) is not available in Ubuntu repos(for 16.04 i think).You need to download it from here :- https://www.eclipse.org/

You can extract it anywhere but I suggest you to extract it in /opt.

```
   sudo tar -xvzf eclipse-cpp-oxygen-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz -C /opt
```

note:- the name `eclipse-cpp-oxygen-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz` can be different in your case.

then you need to make .desktop file which is shown here:- [Create a .desktop file that opens and execute a command in a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal)

### or

you can install eclipse by `sudo apt install eclipse` and then upgrade to latest version from eclipse.

**Source:-** https://www.unixmen.com/install-eclipse-luna-ide-centos-7-rhel-7/

https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-install-eclipse-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/