# starting my c++ console program with startup applications

Tags: 16.04, c++, startup-applications

On ubuntu 16.04, I've made small GUI with c++ and ncurses. Result an .o file.

How do I run that on login with startup applications, and what is required for this to work?

I've tried this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyApp
Exec=/home/mig/Documents/Cpp/MyCode/TXTGUI/txtgui.o
Type=Application
Terminal=true
```

in a .desktop file in .config/autostart, but no luck.

Comment: You probably need to [Create a .desktop file that opens and execute a command in a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

dsstorefile1 your comment lead to a working solution. Thank you for posting.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Test        
Comment=Test the terminal running a command inside it
Exec=bash -c '/home/mig/Documents/Cpp/MyCode/TXTGUI/txtgui.o'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true 
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```