# Automatic uncompressed backup/folder syncing to smb share

Tags: windows, software-recommendation, samba, backup, deja-dup

I have an smb share, an Ubuntu laptop and a Windows Desktop. The Desktop is backing up one of its drives to the smb share using Windows file history (keeping a local copy). If I want I can access that backup (which is just a file copy) from my laptop at any time. Now I would like to the same with my Laptop: back up a specific set of folders (without archiving/zipping them) to smb automatically on a schedule or whenever I manually trigger it assuming that the smb share is available, so that the Windows PC can also read from that backup or keep a local copy of a part of it. I could do it with a cron job and a shell script, but isn't there a neater way with a simple GUI to do that? Just copying folders to smb on a schedule or when triggered manually? I tried deja dup, but it zips the data which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

A GUI is simpler to use but less versatile than your own script, so to have everything you want exactly the way you want it, `cron` and [`rsync`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders) is the way to go as you can still execute the script manually whenever you want.  All GUI backup programs that I'm aware of compress, deduplicate, encrypt, ...

If you want an icon for your script you [can still do that too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal).