# Autostart with Desktop Entry only works for GUI applications

Tags: command-line, raspberrypi, autostart

I am trying to start django with a `Desktop Entry` file and open a chromium browser in kiosk mode to show a locally served website which shows some weather reports for my area etc ...
I put some sleep seconds before starting up the browser because I want to wait for django to start up etc ...

Working:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=ChromeBrowser for weatherdata
Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 20 && chromium-browser --kiosk "127.0.0.1:8001" --start-fullscreen"
```

not working (starting django):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Django Server
Exec=/bin/bash -c "python3 /home/me/app manage.py runserver 8001"
Terminal=true
```

I just never see an open terminal or can find a running python instance with htop. What am I missing? I also find no errors of the desktop entry process when running `journalctl`.
I tried to create my file using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal). Reading the [specification](https://developer-old.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/) did not bring enlightment.

So I have two questions:

1. what am I missing here?
2. where would I find a log of whats happening?
3. (is the only way to make this work to write an sh script that executes my django command?)

Comment: could be the "space" in `app manage.py`. Besides this, it makes more sense to configure and start such background processes with systemd.

Comment: that was exactly the issue! `/home/me/app manage.py` -> `/home/me/app/manage.py` and now it works. Please post as answer, I will accept it. Also: Do you know anything about the logs? And why is systemd the better approach to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space in the app path is the problem or the wrong quotes.

Means, ether remove the space or use correct quotes.

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'python3 "/home/me/app manage.py" runserver 8001'
```

You can test the `.desktop` files from commandline with `gtk-launch` which will show the errors, if any.

```
gtk-launch "/path/to/mycommand.desktop"
```

Using systemd user is usually the more generic way, especially if the program is independent of a graphical environment (e.g. start on ssh login), see `man systemd.unit`. But of course it is a bit more complex. You will find many manuals for this with help of Google.