# How do I open an executable from files in Ubuntu 22?

Tags: executable

I have a few executables compiled with g++. Some are simple hello world programs with sleep statements, others are large projects with GUIs etc.
Running the executables from terminal using `./{executable_name}` works just fine. However when I double click on the executables in 'Files', nothing visible happens. I have tried making a .sh script and clicking on that instead. I have tried `chmod +x {executable_name}` in terminal. Neither have made a difference. Right clicking the executable and going to 'Run' didn't do much either.

The executables don't pop up in the OS banner to the left when you click on them either.

Edit:
Running executables that write to files seems to work. That means that clicking on the icon doesn't work for applications that run in terminal. I guess my question is then, how do I run terminal applications from Files?

Comment: It sounds like you want to [Create a .desktop file that opens and execute a command in a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal)